# Wordpress dbdelta a semicolon

Tags: database, dbdelta

I have a query, something like this

```
$drzava ="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`wp_drzava` (
      `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `Kod` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
      `Naziv` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      `NazivSrb` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      `NazivSrbGenetiv` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      `jePrevedeno` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
      `jeDrzava` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '1',
      `PhoneCode` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
      `NazivRo` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=304 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    INSERT INTO wp_drzava VALUES ('249', 'RO', 'Romania', 'Rumunija', 'Rumunije', null, '1', '+40', 'Rom&#226;nia ')";
```

Problem seems to be in România record, so I get not record inserted. I try `dbDelta()` function and also `$wpdb->query()` but I get no result.

Any suggestions

Answer (score -2):

```
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');

$drzava = "your sql";

dbDelta($drzava);
```

Comment: Please explain _why_ this answer is helpful.